# variations in scanf in C language

Tags: c, scanf

```
scanf("%d %d"+2, &a, &b);
printf("%d\n%d", a, b);
```

It accepts only `a` and prints `a` and `0`.
Can anyone explain why this is happening?
Also, if I write `+1` instead of `+2`, it accepts nothing and prints `0` and `0`.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
scanf("%d %d"+2,&a,&b);
```

is the same as

```
scanf(" %d", &a, &b);
```

which is the same as

```
scanf("%d", &a, &b);
```

which means that the extra `&b` argument is unnecessary.

What happens here is that `"%d %d"` is a `char*`. Adding two to it results into a pointer pointing two bytes ahead which means that it now points to `" %d"`. The leading space is unnecessary because `%d` already skips leading whitespace characters.

---

When you use `+1` instead of `+2`, the `scanf` is the same as

```
scanf("d %d", &a, &b);
```

which means that it expects a `d` in the input followed by an integer to be assigned to `a`. Since you provide a number instead of `d` in the input, the `scanf` fails and returns 0. Thus, nothing is accepted and the execution reaches the `printf` which prints the value of both `a` and `b`.